# SQL Server - Best way to sum 2 fields based on different groupings

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have a table in SQL Server that looks as follows:

```
MyTable:
Col1:     Col2:    Col3:     Val1:     Val2:
1         2        a         1         1
1         2        a         1         1
1         2        b         1         1
1         2        b         1         1
1         2        c         1         1
1         2        c         1         1
```

So, I am looking to create a query that returns:

1. `Sum(Val1)` based on the values in `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3`

**AND**

2. `Sum(Val2)` based on the values in `Col1`, `Col2` only

So, I came up with the following query that can accomplish this:

```
with MyData as
(
    select distinct
        Col1
        , Col2
        , Col3
        , sum(Val1) over(partition by Col1, Col2, Col3) as Value1,
        , sum(Val2) over(partition by Col1, Col2) as Value2
    from 
        MyTable
)

Select * from MyData
```

Yielding something along the lines of:

```
Result:
Col1:     Col2:    Col3:     Value1:     Value2:
1         2        a         2           6
1         2        b         2           6
1         2        c         2           6
```

This works, but it seems terribly inefficient due to the `Distinct` - Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: why you called inefficient? Did you run `explain plan` ?

Comment: You could try two separated `GROUP BY` and then `JOIN` back together, but again you need have `EXPLAIN PLAN` so you can compare both

Comment: Thanks, @JuanCarlosOropeza, I did make up the execution plan, but am always hoping there's just some kind of function or something that SQL Server allows for that I just don't know exists and would be more efficient.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't characterize the DISTINCT as "terribly inefficient", and no, I don't think there's a "better way" to accomplish your desired results.

Comment: Thanks - I'm just always hoping there's a more efficient SQL construct that I'm just unaware of or something.